# Show that $e^x > x^t$ where $x > 0$ and $t < e$

Tags: calculus

Question as per the title.

Show that $e^x > x^t$ where $x > 0$ and $t < e$

It was suggested that to arrive at the proof, the maclaurin series be used.

Comment: One possible way to think about it: $x^t=e^{t\log x}$.

Comment: Please show any working you have done, you're more likely to get positive responses that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $x^t= e^{t \log x}$. Then $e^x > x^t$ iff $t < x/\log x$. Now, for $x>0$, the minimum value of $x/\log x$ is $e$, attained at $x=e$.